Custom Login in Auth0 Social Login giving invalid user id
Hi I have been trying to do custom social login and I have setup all accordingly, including the Fetch User Script. I am not sure where I am doing wrong. I put the url correctly ‘https://{mydomain}/userinfo’
function fetchUserProfile(accessToken, context, callback) {
request.get(
{
  url: 'https://mydomain/userinfo',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
  }
},
(err, resp, body) => {
  if (err) {
    return callback(err);
  }
  if (resp.statusCode !== 200) {
    return callback(new Error(body));
  }
  let bodyParsed;
  try {
    bodyParsed = JSON.parse(body);
  } catch (jsonError) {
    return callback(new Error(body));
  }
  const profile = {
    user_id: bodyParsed.sub,
    email: bodyParsed.email
  };
  callback(null, profile);
}
);
}

this is my Fetch User Profile Script
